# PHP - MultiProcessing(Using different cores)

Tags: php, multiprocessing

I am writing a Cron in PHP which is supposed to run every hour and it is supposed to convert the last 10 videos in a directory to mp4 format.

The problem is the conversion time of each video in 15 minutes, therefore in an hour, only 4 videos get converted.

I have a quadcore CPU, therefore, i want to try out Multiprocessing in PHP. I want each video to be assigned to a core so that 4 videos are converted in parallel.

Therefore, the first batch will have 4 videos conversions in parallel and will finish in 15 minutes. The second batch will have the next 4 video conversions in parallel and will finish in the next 15 minutes.

The last 2 videos will be converted likewise in the next 15 minutes. Therefore, by using the multiprocessing model, 10 videos can be converted in 45 minutes, which works for me.

So how do i achieve MultiProcessing in PHP? I read some info on pecl threads in php but i was ensure if multithreading will actually use all the 4 cores of my CPU.

Comment: What converter do you use? It might be able to use multiple cores.

Comment: Don't use php: use ffmpeg and bash.

Comment: I am using FFMPEG already. So u mean, i should write a shell script?

Comment: But what is the guarantee that the shell script would be using different cores?

Comment: I didn't know you were using FFMPEG already. Solution below is probably what you are looking for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest way is to run your script multiple times and not worry about multiprocessing:

```
1  *   *     *     * php /path/to/script
2  *   *     *     * php /path/to/script
3  *   *     *     * php /path/to/script
4  *   *     *     * php /path/to/script


15  *   *     *     * php /path/to/script
16  *   *     *     * php /path/to/script
17  *   *     *     * php /path/to/script
18  *   *     *     * php /path/to/script
```

Use [flock()](http://php.net/flock) to let the script know which file to process:

```
foreach(glob('dir/*.avi') as $file) {
    $lockfile = fopen($file . '.lock', 'a+');
    if(flock($lockfile)) {
        // do the processing
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Oh then the OS handles the multi processing itself?

Comment: Yes. You just need to make sure you don't run processing on the same file multiple times. That's what the flock is for.